# What kind of grammatical form is this?/ Что это за грамматическая форма?

Tags: морфология

***Он ревмя ревёт.***

It's clear that the phrase means an intensive and, possibly, frequentative action. But what is the grammatical meaning of the phrase? Is it a productive pattern?

Понятно, что фраза означает некое интенсивное и, предположительно, фреквентативное действие. Но каково грамматическое значение фразы? Насколько продуктивна конструкция?

Comment: ... и кишмя кишит. :)

Comment: congrats, this is a very nice question, I'll try to give an answer to this tomorrow.

Comment: Ещё подобные выраженя: сиднем сидеть, ходить ходуном, поедом есть, стоймя стоять, бежма бежать, кричма кричать. Выражения образованы по тавтологической модели - редупликацией глагола, характерной для народной русской речи, эти выражения разговорные.

Comment: @Yellow Sky: Вас не смущает тот факт, что в некоторых конструкциях повторяется формат "мя"/"ма"? И что наряду с "кричма кричать" есть "криком кричать"?

Comment: Чего это меня должно смущать? Формы на -мя и -ма - это наречия, образованные от глаголов.

Comment: И каким же именно образом от глаголов образовались наречия с использованием показателя двойственного числа существительных?

Comment: Глаголы заканчивающиеся на -ся, смотреться, чесаться, качаться. Что такое -ся? Это `себя`. Смотреть себя, чесать себя, качать себя. Можно предположить что -мя, значит `меня`?

Answer (score 8):

*Ревмя, кричмя, лежмя* and similar are adverbs, derived from reduplicated nominalized verbs in dual instrumental.

The traces of this now extinct number are preserved in Russian word *двумя* (which had also influenced *тремя* and *четырьмя*), and also in Ukrainian *очима, плечима*.

This model is similar to *сидеть сиднем, волочь волоком*; however instead of du. inst., sg. inst. is used in these examples.

According to Vinogradov, this model is quite productive due to its proximity to adverbial participles (*ревя, крича, лёжа*), even though usage of dual is not justified anymore:

> Несомненно, что в современном языке с этими группами наречий сближаются и глагольно-именные формы на *-мя, -ма*: *ливмя, лежмя, стоймя — стойма, ревмя* и др.; ср. *плашмя.*
>
> Даже если видеть в суффиксе *-мя* отложение древних именных флексий двойственного числа (ср.: *двумя, тремя*), все же трудно отрицать для современного языкового сознания их морфологическую близость к наречиям типа *лежа, сидя* и т. п. Функционально же они не отделимы от фразеологических сочетаний, возникающих из творительного усиления: *есть поедом, ходить ходуном* и т. д.
>
> …
>
> Все эти отглагольные группы наречий сближаются с наречиями образа действия. В них очень ощутительны качественно-обстоятельственные оттенки (ср.: *крадучись* и *украдкой*, *умеючи* и *умело* и т. п.).
>
> Оттенок усиления, свойственный словам *ливмя, стоймя* и т. п., объясняется их тавтологическим или плеонастическим употреблением при словах той же основы или сходного значения (ср.: *стоном стонать, бегом бежать* и т. п.).

The adverbs *плашмя, весьма, задарма* follow the similar model, though they are derived from nouns and pronouns, not nominalized verbs.

Comment: плашмя, кажется, всё-таки тоже отглагольное.

Comment: @shabunc и от какого глагола?

Comment: @shabunc: it's clearly originated from a noun which is an ancestor to modern *плашка*.

Comment: Благодарю за подробный и развернутый ответ. Но каким именно образом показатель двойственного числа существительных стал показателем отглагольных наречий? И когда?

Comment: @Manjusri: don't understand your question. Russian adverbs don't have a specific marker, most of them originated from other parts of speech which just took the adverbial function. Say, *чудом* (as in *спаслись чудом*) originated from sg. inst. of *чудо* and is indistinguishable from the latter out of context, but as an adverb is answers "how? (как?)", not "what with? (чем?)".

Comment: @Quassnoi Yes, but what were the original noun forms for those adverbs? It is clear about чудом that it is a modification of  чудо. What about ливмя/ревмя/кричма/стоймя/бежма? Why some verbs take -ма while the others take -мя endings? It seems not quite historically justifiable.

Comment: @Manjusri: "reduplicated nominalized verbs". Those nouns are invented for the pleonastic purposes, they are meaningless by themselves. What do you mean by "historically justifiable"?

Comment: @Quassnoi, if those nouns are invented, then what are their initial forms, and what are the historical forms? How any form of Old Russian dualis could take a -мя-ending? And it's clear about криком/сиднем/ходуном/поедом. The initial forms are clear there. Which is not quite the case about the -ма/-мя endings.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7396/discussion-between-quassnoi-and-manjusri)